# Jenkins to pass SVN_DIR variable to promoting job

Tags: maven, svn, jenkins

I have a maven build job which provides drop-down list to select the project under SVN trunk. I have used promoted builds plugin to promote the build to different environments. I want to pass SVN_DIR variable to my promotional job as parameter. I have used predefined parameters and defined as SVN_DIR=${SVN_DIR}, to check if I am able to pass when I tried to echo SVN_DIR value it is showing as SVN_DIR itself. This means it is not passing the value. Any idea how to achieve this?jenkins

Answer (score 0):

You can use Parameterized Trigger Plugin which will let you to pass parameters from one job to another which can be found here https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Trigger+Plugin

Answer (score 0):

OR you can use the [Promoted Builds Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Promoted+Builds+Plugin). The original SVN_DIR will be available as PROMOTED_SVN_DIR.

Comment: How Do I reteieve the SVN_DIR on downstream job? Do I need to use ${PROMOTED_SVN_DIR} instead of ${SVN_DIR}?

Comment: Yes. I have only done this with Git but this is home it should work. And you have to call the stuff you would normally do form the other job during the build promotion.